# characterisation of etale morphism of rings

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, etale-cohomology

I am reading Freitag’s etale cohomology and Weil conjecture. He says that A finitely generated flat algebra $A \rightarrow B$ is etale if and only if the following condition is satisfied-
For every prime ideal $p \subset A$ , the algebra $B \underset{A} {\otimes}k(p)$ is finite separable over $k(p)$. Here $k(p)$ is quotient field of $A/p$ and finite separable means that it can be written as finite cartesian product of finite seperable extensions of $k(p)$.

Can someone help me on this?
Edit: 
A ring homomorphism $A \rightarrow$ B is called etale if the following conditions are satisfied:
a) $ B $ is finitely generated $A $ algebra.
b) $B$ is a flat $A$ module.
c) $A \rightarrow B$ is unramified, that is , all localisations $A_q \rightarrow B_p $ are unramified ($p$ is prime ideal of $B$ , $q = p \cap A$ ). 
\

A local homomorphism is called unramified if the following conditions are satisfied:
a) $m(A).B = m(A)$, and
b)the residue field extension is finite and separable.

Comment: $B \otimes_A \kappa (\mathfrak{p})$ may not be a field. For example, the diagonal $A \to A \times A$ is étale.

Comment: The sentence "we are done if..." is easily shown to be false: take $A=B=\Bbb Q[x,x^{-1}]$ where the map is $x\mapsto x^2$. Then for $p=(x-1)$, $B\otimes_A k(p)\cong B/(x^2-1)\cong \Bbb Q^2$.

Comment: Yes you are right. So how it will be done?

Comment: What is your (or rather Freitag’s) definition of étale? For these “iff” questions you should state definitions.

Comment: @ZhenLin I have added definitions to the question.

Comment: OK. Do you see that your definition has the property that $A \to B$ is étale if and only if, for every prime ideal $\mathfrak{p} \subset A$, $A_\mathfrak{p} \to B \otimes_A A_\mathfrak{p}$ is étale? That will let you reduce to the case where $A$ is a local ring.

Comment: Can you please elaborate?